# Mongo DB- Update document field if a particular field has more than one document matches

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data

### Scenario

Example Mongo DB documents
Doc 1
{
_id 123
Customer: customer A
State: TX
City: Houston
checksum: 1111
IsBundlled:
}

Doc 2
{
_id 1234
Customer: customer B
State: TX
City: Houston
checksum: 1111
IsBundlled:
}

Doc 3
{
_id 12345
Customer: customer c
State: NY
City: Buffalo
checksum: 2222
IsBundlled:

}

Checksum field is populated in app code using State and City fields.

### Problem

Populate IsBundled field for each document to true, if a checksum matches more than 1 documents. In our case 1st and 2nd documents needs to updated with isBundled: true .  Instead of adding this logic in application code, I am looking for better solutions  using aggregation pipeline

Also how to perform this aggregation in app code via Spring Boot Mongo AggregationUpdate class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$merge` is available from versions greater than MongoDB 4.4

As `$merge` at the **end of aggregation pipeline** is necessary to **update the collection through aggregation.**

**For more information about** `$merge` : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/

`$group:` To group the matching documents. 
`$set:` To modify the document 
`$gt:` To check if greater than condition 
`$replaceRoot:` To replace the current document structure by another.

**MongoDB Playground link** : https://mongoplayground.net/p/pV_UbQ-ADby

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$checksum",
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      },
      bundles: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$bundles"
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "bundles.IsBundled": {
        $gt: [
          "$count",
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$bundles"
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
"$group": {
  "_id": "$checksum",
   "toUpdate": {
    "$addToSet": "$_id"
   },
  cnt: {
    $sum: 1
    }
  }
  },
  {
   $match: {
    cnt: {
      $gt: 1
   }
  }
 }
 ]).toArray().forEach(function(d){ db.collection.update({_id:{$in:d.toUpdate}},{$set:{ IsBundled:"true" }})   },{multi:true})
```

[aggregation playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9Wl_HRCuG9Q)

Explained:

1. Group on checksum and get document _id per same checksum
2. Filter checksum matching more then one document
3. Loop over the result to update all the documents with duplicated checksum with IsBundled: true

Comment: Upvoting this but if the the aggregate resulted in thousands or even millions of documents it would not be very efficient as you would be doing 1 update per id.

Comment: @jQueeny : made some small improvement , removed the unwind stage and changed the update to match based on $in:[]  with multi:true so to update multiple matching in single update operation ...

Comment: That would work a treat with and if the `_id` is indexed (I imagine it is) the `$in` should benefit from using it.

Comment: Another option I am thinking of  that maybe more optimal is as per @Aniket answer below , but copy in advance the original collection to newCollection and add a $merge stage at the end to replace the matching documents in the newCollection ( since you cannot do $merge to same collection )

Comment: ah it looks $merge to same collection is possible with version > 4.2 so maybe this is your best option ...

Comment: I think that should be possible. Might need to do some testing to check the results.